# Commit a modification to SVN using SVNKit with a particular check in date

Tags: svn, svnkit

I'm trying to migrate a different repository with a different source control system to SVN. I have the revisions / file structure / etc checking in correctly, but at the moment I'm losing the history of when the files were checked in (as obviously it's using the current time of check in).

Is there any way I can specify a check in time?

Comment: Do you mean different Subversion repository? You must not use client-side tools for this, but admin tools like `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load`, http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/admin/SVNAdminClient.html It actually looks like you are trying to reinvent `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I'm transferring from a different source control altogether.